# "implicit conversion from <tuple type> to <tuple type 2> requires a temporary" error when passing a tuple as an inout argument

Tags: swift, tuples, inout

This is my code:

```
var myTuple = ("bar", 42)

func foo(_ bar: inout (arg1: String, arg2: Double)) {
    [...]
}

foo(&myTuple)
```

I get the following error for this line:

```
foo(&myTuple)
```

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from '(String, Double)' to '(arg1: String, arg2: Double)' requires a temporary

Answer (score 3):

The actual problem is that your tuple variable is **missing labels** that are present in the function. Replace it with the following:

```
var myTuple = (arg1: "bar", arg2: 42)
```

[Explanation by @Hamish:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49894807/3151675#comment86811871_49894923)

> The problem is that an implicit conversion is required for a `(String, Int)` to match up with a `(arg1: String, arg2: Int)` – by performing the implicit coercion, the compiler ends up with a temporary rvalue which cannot then be passed inout. That's why the error (somewhat confusingly) talks about an immutable value.

Comment: But interestingly, the error does *only* occur with inout parameters. You *can* pass `account3` to a `func foo(_ account: (name:String,balance: Double))`

Comment: @MartinR Hmm, interesting. Error messages like this are not informative at all. I don't even know what "requires a temporary" means.

Comment: I found some leads on the "requires a temporary", but i'm not able to describe why, what or how this works. Maybe @MartinR or the4kman is?

CSDiag.cpp:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3db30f9de43cf66ef09e85e61f84c715dda53b4c/lib/Sema/CSDiag.cpp#L2808
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3db30f9de43cf66ef09e85e61f84c715dda53b4c/lib/Sema/CSDiag.cpp#L759

LValueType:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/db8b98bbc965e0452903ca4605dfa28edb202d4b/include/swift/AST/Types.h#L4405

TypeCoercion test:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/TypeCoercion/protocols.swift#L115

Comment: The problem is that an implicit conversion is required for a `(String, Int)` to match up with a `(arg1: String, arg2: Int)` – by performing the implicit conversion, the compiler ends up with a temporary rvalue which cannot then be passed `inout`. That's why the error (somewhat confusingly) talks about an immutable value.

Comment: @Hamish Thank you for this additional information, I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **You have two options to do that**

**First: DO like that**

```
var account3 = (name: "state bank personal", balance: 1000.00)
```

**Or Second: Change method and use like that**

```
func desposit0(amount:Double,account:inout (String,Double))->(String,Double)
```

> **use:** account.0 and account.1